# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, android-spinner, sqliteopenhelper

I got that Error. How could I eliminate the android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@ instead of INTEGER value alone? And how could I get the integer Value from my consumer table which is AccountID and Save it as FOREiGN KEY into my consumptions table? 
My Spinner Handler

```
private void loadSpinnerData() {
    // database handler

    SQLiteDatabase db = new DatabaseOpenHelper(this).getWritableDatabase();

    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    // Spinner Drop down elements
    // List<String> lables = db.getAllLabels();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(
            "SELECT AccountID AS _id, ConsumerName FROM Consumers", null);
    startManagingCursor(c);

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    String[] from = new String[] { "_id"};
    int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
    SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c, from, to);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    // set spinner listener to display the selected item id
    mContext = this;

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // On selecting a spinner item
            //String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Cursor c = (Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
             mSpinnerSpeciesId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Selected ID=" + c,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Showing selected spinner item
            /*
             * Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected: " + label,
             * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             */

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
```

My SaveContact into my database

```
    private void saveContact() {

    DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

    if (getIntent().getExtras() == null) {

        dbConnector.insertConsumption(meterNoEt.getText().toString(),
                currentEt.getText().toString(), previousEt.getText()
                        .toString(), kWhEt.getText().toString(), dateTv
                        .getText().toString(), spinner.getSelectedItem()
                        .toString()

        );

    } else {
        dbConnector.updateConsumption(rowID,
                currentEt.getText().toString(), previousEt.getText()
                        .toString(), kWhEt.getText().toString(), dateTv
                        .getText().toString(), spinner.getSelectedItem()
                        .toString());

    }
}
```

And I Got this Error!

```
02-18 23:42:26.321: E/SQLiteDatabase(29864): Error inserting ConsumerName=android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@4144bbe0 kWh=40300.0 _id=355477 Date=2013 -2-18 Previous=5587 Current=45887
```

Comment: I Figure it out. Thanks for this link. http://www.samcoles.co.uk/mobile/android-populate-a-spinner-from-your-sqlite-database/